# VB Type Mismatch issues - inArray()

Tags: arrays, asp-classic, vbscript, function

I'm not much of a VB programmer but something like this should be simple enough... I'm really stumped here though.

I have a web app that does a lot of work with emails and PDFs. I'm adding a few new functions to it and have run into two very basic "Type Mismatch" errors and haven't been able to solve them.

The first happens when I call inArray() in a simple find/replace script. I make an array of the field names in a database and compare the content of an email to these names so that $*%%P1FirstName can be replaced by the actual first name in the DB. Simple enough.

This exact code works elsewhere in the site, but on this new page I get the Type Mismatch error on the line containing the inArray() call:

```
strOut = ""
strIn = strEmail
arrString = split(strIn,"$*")
'make an array of all the fields in the recordset to compare the fields in the email against
strTmp = ""
for each f in rs2.fields
    strTmp = strTmp & f.name & "x%x"
next
arrFields = split(strTmp,"x%x")
for i = lbound(arrString) to ubound(arrString)
    'if the current word in the array is a DB field name (as indicated by the leading '%%' then get the data
    'from the recordset and drop it into the email, otherwise it is a generic term
    if left(arrString(i),2) = "%%" then
        arrString(i) = replace(arrString(i),"%%","")
        if not trim(arrString(i)) = "" then
            if inArray(arrFields, arrString(i)) then
                strOut = strOut & rs2(arrString(i))
            end if
        end if
    else
        strOut = strOut & arrString(i)
    end if
next
```

I can't figure out why two arrays of strings can't be compared (or why this same call works elsewhere). Nothing seems to be off when I output anything (like the field names) and excessive CStr() use isn't helping.

The other one is just a function call:

WritePDF( iformID, TemplateFile, Appfile, signed, rsProc("fontSize"),passwordProtect )

where signed and password protect are booleans. It's more complicated because the error doesn't tell me specifically which field is off. I've just been trying a bunch of rephrasing and cbool() and manually setting each field and not getting anywhere. Again, this same code works on every other page in the site.

I'm sure there's a very simple answer for these and it's driving me nuts that I haven't found it. If there's something you notice immediately I'd love to get feedback.

Answer (score 1):

There is no built in function called InArray() in vbscript. Do you have the function included?

Answer (score 0):

This ***exact code*** works elsewhere?  Are you sure you're passing the arguments to the inArray() function in the right order?  A string array and a string passed in the wrong order would cause a Type Mismatch error.

Comment: exact code... I have since solved this. It has nothing to do with a Type Mismatch at all... inArray() isn't a built in function like I thought it was, it's in an include that I forgot to include. It never occurred to me because the error was so far from "undefined function", which would make sense.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this instead:

```
strOut = ""
strIn = strEmail

strTmp = ""
For Each f In rs2.fields
    If Instr(strIn, "$*%%" & f.name) > 0 Then
        strIn = Replace(strIn, "$*%%" & f.name, rs2(f.Name).Value)
    End If
Next

strOut = strIn
```